# apt-get ignores my dotdeb repositories

Tags: apt

I got a server from my university computer center, which is a managed server. I'm root on that server.

Now I'm trying to add the [dotdeb sources for php 5.6](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/). I did this on my own server and it was piece of cake, by simply [following the instructions](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) and adding the sources list to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

The problem I get now is that I can't do this on the new server the exact same way, because sources.list is managed by the server. Instead I have to add a file in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

So I created the file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/alamp.list
```

with the following entries

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts all
```

The command `apt-get update` seems to see those sources, but it doesn't install php 5.6. It (apt-get update) gives the following lines for php 5.6

```
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy/all Translation-en
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts/all Translation-en
```

But also somewhere before that it gives:

```
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts/all Sources
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts/all amd64 Packages
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue? I want to install php 5.6.

### Please ask for any additional information if you need it.

Requests from comments:

```
apt-cache policy php5

php5:
  Installed: 5.4.36-1~dotdeb.1
  Candidate: 5.4.36-1~dotdeb.1
  Version table:
     5.6.5-1~dotdeb.1 0
        500 http://packages.dotdeb.org/ wheezy-php56-zts/all amd64 Packages
 *** 5.4.36-1~dotdeb.1 0
        700 http://packages.dotdeb.org/ wheezy/all amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.36-0+deb7u3 0
        700 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.36-0+deb7u1 0
        700 http://ftp.uni-mainz.de/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        700 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @Braiam Just apt-get update and upgrade. I keep getting php 5.4 and it's not upgrading. This worked though on my personal server.

Comment: `apt-cache policy pkgname` please.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I added the output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Faheem, with his comment he put me on the right path to google the right things.

It turns out that the problem was that the university had a file

```
/etc/apt/preferences
```

which included definition of priorities of stuff to be installed. Once I removed this, an upgrade with `apt-get dist-upgrade` happened alone.